# how to get EMR cluster version from a running cluster

Tags: amazon-emr

I have several accounts and they run different versions of EMR.  I need to run a query to figure out what version (list-release-labels) they are running.  I see the list-release-labels but it is not very intuitive.  It looks as if I have to use list-clusters --active and maybe list-release-labels.

Appreciate for any pointers

Thanks

this just gives me the list of active clusters.  I need to findout the release/version

aws emr list-clusters --active --query "Clusters[*].{ClusterName:Name}" --output text

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no EMR API that would list clusters *and* include the release label in the response, so you will have to list your clusters first (using `aws emr list-clusters`) and then look up the release label being used by the cluster (using `aws emr describe-cluster`). The `list-release-labels` command is completely unrelated and is used for listing the available release labels that *could* be used when creating clusters.

Here is some example shell script code that could be used to look up the release label for each of your active clusters:

```
for cluster in $(aws emr list-clusters --active --query 'Clusters[*].Id' --output text); do
  echo -n "$cluster\t"
  aws emr describe-cluster --cluster-id $cluster --query 'Cluster.ReleaseLabel' --output text
done
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  I am going to use the info